# Lumen 5.6 seeJson() fails

Tags: lumen, laravel-5.6

I was testing for an api validation that has a custom error message, when I run the unit test, this gives me this error:

```
LinkCreationTest::fails_if_no_url_given
Unable to find JSON fragment ["url":"Please enter a URL to shorten."] within [{"url":["Please enter a URL to shorten."]}].
Failed asserting that false is true
```

**LinkController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'url' => 'required|url'
    ],[
        'url.required' => 'Please enter a URL to shorten.'
    ]);
}
```

**web.php**

`$router->post('/', 'LinkController@store');`

**LinkCreationTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function fails_if_no_url_given()
{
   $response = $this->json('POST', '/')    
            ->notSeeInDatabase('links',[
                'code' => '1'
            ])
            ->seeJson(['url' => 'Please enter a URL to shorten.']) 
            ->assertResponseStatus(422);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `LinkController.php` is returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using [] on the value of seeJson

```
->seeJson(['url' => ['Please enter a URL to shorten.'] ])
```